# How to define global variable inside a function?

Tags: javascript, global-variables

I want to just define a global variable inside a function in javascript, I don't want to assign any value to it. I have tried following:

```
<script>
    function defineGlobal(){
        window.gl_var;
        console.log(gl);
    }      
</script>
```

I am expecting the gl_var as undefined. But it gives reference error.

Comment: Why bother setting it? You're not going to get a reference error even if you don't create it first. If you absolutely must create it, why not set it to `null`?

Comment: @ h2ooooooo : I just want to define, I don't want to assign any value to it.

Comment: But **why**? If you simply call `window.gl_var` the response is **already** `undefined`.

Comment: Simply `window.gl_var = undefined` or `window.gl_var = (function() {})();` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use "gl_var = undefined". That should suffice ;-)
Look at the 'x' below.

```
js>x = undefined
js>undefined
js>x
js>undefined
js>var y
js>undefined
```

Comment: Thanks Prince for your valuable answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can't define a variable without assigning it some value. Is there a reason you need a variable that can contain literally any possible value? If not, you can set it to some sentinel -`null` often works for this- and check for that value to see if the variable has been "set" or not.

Another possible option would be to use two variables: the one you actually intend to hold a value, and a boolean that starts out false but that your program sets to true the first time that variable gets used. You could even wrap this up in a small object with `obj.getValue()`, `obj.setValue(newValue)`, and `obj.valueHasBeenSet()` functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can not define global variable inside function as you are doing `window.gl_var;` it is trying to call `gl_var` and did not find it so it is throwing error.

Comment: Is there any other method to define global variable inside a function?

Comment: Why you want to define global variable inside function? Just declare it globally and initialize it's value from your function so I think it will satisfy your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

using an undefined variable in javascript just breaks everything, define it first

`var gl_var="";` or `var gl_var=null;`

```
function defineGlobal(){
        window.gl_var;
        console.log(gl);
    }
```

Comment: *"using an undefined variable in javascript just breaks everything"*. Completely incorrect. When referring to an object variable (`window` is an object`), you simply get `undefined` if it doesn't exist. Your code would still fail as `console.log(gl)` looks for a variable named `gl` which has never been created (not in the function scope and nor in the global scope).

Comment: @h2ooooooo: An "object variable" is not a variable, but a property?